# Error in downloading file PHP

Tags: php, download

I have a link which shows the filename to download.When a user clicks it,it needs to get downloaded.The file gets downloaded but it contains only 0 KB.In console it shows

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/force-download:       "../download.php?file=filename"

My code is like this:

```
<a href="download.php?file=user_uploads/'.$_path['uploads'].
'logo_images/'.$row['FileName'].'" title="Click to download">'.$row['FileName'].'</a>
```

The download.php is like this:

```
<?php       
$path   =   str_replace('/download.php?file=','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);  
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($path . $uri[1]) . "\"" );   
@readfile($path);  
?>
```

Thanks in advance.I have checked the path of the file also.

Comment: Do not suppress error with `@` when you debug.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169636/php-file-download-headers

Comment: You should check the file that is being request, otherwise one can download *any* file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<a href="yourpath_to_download.php?file=file.txt" title="Click to download">Click</a>
```

download.php

```
<?php       
$path   = 'yourpath'.$_GET['file'];  
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['file'] );   
@readfile($path);  
?>
```

file.txt - change with your file name

Comment: I have used '$path   = `yourpath'.$_GET['file'];` earlier.The thing is that if a filename contains & symbol,filename is broken because of & symbol,ie the browswer thinks the filename as 2 filenames and the file is not downloading.(eg:filename os jh&ju.txt,$path variable will get only `jh`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while downloading my file. I used this code for download.php:

```
<?php

$path = $_REQUEST['path'];

#setting headers
   header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
   header('Cache-Control: public');
   header('Content-Type: application/zip');
   header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. basename($path));
   header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path));
   ob_clean(); #THIS!
   flush();
   readfile($path);

exit;
?>
```

and my link was:

```
<a href="file.php?path='.$encodedPath.'" name="download" class="acction" ">Download Pack</a>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is $packPath? @AppleBud

Comment: Sorry, that was typo. it is nothing but the path variable.